# Spark SQL- How to Convert RelationalGroupedDataSet to DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Hi,

In my problem, I need to group the DataFrame, apply the business logic for each group and finally emit a new DataFrame based on that. To describe in detail, there is a `device_dataframe` which contains the timestamp of when the device had been turned on (`on`) and turned off (`off`).

```scala
+---------+----- +--------------------+
|device_id|state |   d_ts             |
+---------+----- +--------------------+
|1        |on    |2020-09-01 16:14:58 |
|1        |off   |2020-09-10 16:14:58 |
|1        |on    |2020-09-19 16:14:58 |
|2        |on    |2020-09-20 16:14:58 |
|2        |off   |2020-10-03 16:14:58 |
|4        |on    |2020-09-20 16:14:58 |
|5        |off   |2020-09-20 16:14:58 |
+---------+-----+-------+-------------+
```

On the other hand, there is a DataFrame containing events information including its timestamp and its corresponding device.

```scala
+-----+---------+--------------------+
|e_id |device_id|       e_ts         |
+-----+---------+--------------------+
|1    |1        |2020-09-20 16:14:58 |
|2    |2        |2020-10-08 09:19:55 |
|3    |4        |2020-11-01 12:15:37 |
|4    |5        |2020-10-08 01:35:08 |
+-----+---------+-------+------------+
```

The following is a join example of two DataFrames:

```scala
+---------+-----+--------------------+------+--------------------+
|device_id|e_id |       e_ts         |state |   d_ts             |
+---------+-----+--------------------+------+--------------------+
|1        |1    |2020-09-20 16:14:58 |on    |2020-09-01 16:14:58 |
|1        |1    |2020-09-20 16:14:58 |off   |2020-09-10 16:14:58 |
|1        |1    |2020-09-20 16:14:58 |on    |2020-09-19 16:14:58 |
|2        |2    |2020-10-08 09:19:55 |on    |2020-09-20 16:14:58 |
|2        |2    |2020-10-08 09:19:55 |off   |2020-10-03 16:14:58 |
|4        |3    |2020-11-01 12:15:37 |on    |2020-09-20 16:14:58 |
|5        |4    |2020-10-08 01:35:08 |off   |2020-09-20 16:14:58 |
+---------+-----+-------+--------------------+------+------------+
```

What I finally need to find is the events information that happened while its corresponding device was `on`. For example in the case of the above table, the event_id `1` is valid because it happened on `2020-09-20 16:14:58` and its device has been `on` since `2020-09-19 16:14:58`, and the event_id `2` is not valid as its device was turned down on `2020-10-03 16:14:58` and never turned on again, and so on.

**Update1**: The other information I need is the number of times a device has been set to `on` before an event happened, which results in the following table:

```scala
+---------+-----+----------+-------------------+
|device_id|e_id | on_count |       e_ts        |
+---------+-----+----------+-------------------+
|1        |1    |    2     |2020-09-20 16:14:58|
|4        |3    |    1     |2020-11-01 12:15:37|
+---------+-----+----------+-------------------+
```

In the above table, the `on_count` value for event id `1` is 2 because when it happened on `2020-09-20 16:14:58`, the device_id `1` had been turned_on two times.

I did the below to group the join table base on the devices:

```scala
val grouped = eventDF
      .join(deviceDF, "device_id")
      .groupBy("device_id")
```

which results in `RelationalGroupedDataSet`. Now I need to apply the logic to each group and emit the result DataFrame but I didn't find a solution for that. I checked the `UDAF`s but I found it not working in my case.

I know how to solve this using RDD API, but I want to find its **Column API** approach.
Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the last state for each `device_id` using the logic below, and filter the rows where the last state is `on`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val result = eventDF
    .join(deviceDF, "device_id")
    .withColumn(
        "last_state",
        max(when($"d_ts" < $"e_ts", array($"d_ts", $"state"))).over(Window.partitionBy("device_id", "e_id"))(1)
    )
    .withColumn(
        "on_count",
        count(when($"state" === "on" && $"d_ts" < $"e_ts", 1)).over(Window.partitionBy("device_id", "e_id"))
    )
    .filter("last_state = 'on'")
    .select("device_id", "e_id", "on_count", "e_ts")
    .distinct

result.show
+---------+----+--------+-------------------+
|device_id|e_id|on_count|               e_ts|
+---------+----+--------+-------------------+
|        1|   1|       2|2020-09-20 16:14:58|
|        4|   3|       1|2020-11-01 12:15:37|
+---------+----+--------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Nice approach, thanks. I also need to have the number of times a device has been turned on (`on`) when each valid event happened. I updated my question with the desired output which for events 1 and 3  the `on_count` value is 2 and 1, respectively (meaning that for example when event 1 happened by then the device had been set to `on` twice)

Comment: It seems you considered all `on`s in each partition of `device_id` but we need to take into account only `on`s that happened before event_ts in each partition.

Comment: @SoheilPourbafrani added another condition in the count. is that alright?

Comment: Thanks, trying with some other data it seems the `when($"d_ts" < $"e_ts"` expression doesn't work in neither cases. For example, the event_ts is `2020-09-28 12:00:00` but its aggregated array value for `last_state` column is `[2020-09-30 12:00:00, on]` so that means the condition  `$"d_ts" < $"e_ts"` is not working as expected as `2020-09-30 12:00:00` is greater than `2020-09-28 12:00:00`

Comment: @SoheilPourbafrani could you please post the relevant sample data? I can't reproduce this problem even if I added another row in device df.

Comment: Please post an example dataframe, and show the corresponding output of the code

Comment: I really appreciate your help man, I just updated the question (Update2) with the join DataFrame, the expected DF, and what I'm getting as a result of your solution.

Comment: @SoheilPourbafrani try edited answer? you can partition by `e_id` as well.